# check if every element in tuple are same type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a function that check if **all the elements of the tuple** are of the **same type**.

e.g. :

```
auto('red', 42, {1,2,3}) #return False

auto('red', "aa", "hgbnj") #return True
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance`:

```
def auto(*tup):
    return all(isinstance(i, type(tup[0])) for i in tup)
```

Or:

```
def auto(*tup):
    return len(set(map(type, tup))) == 1
```

Example:

```
print(auto('red', "aa", "hgbnj"))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Example 2:

```
print(auto('red', 42, {1,2,3}))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a set and map each value to a `type`

```
def auto(*values):
    return len(set(map(type, values))) == 1
```